# how to add register_post_type in add_submenu_page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I would like to know if this is possible in wordpress adding my `register_post_type` to my `add_submenu_page`. I'm trying to search it into google but failed to do it.

```
function fd_sample_list(){

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'sample list', 'sample_list' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'sample list', 'sample_list' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'sample_list' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New sample list', 'sample_list' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit sample list', 'sample_list' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New sample list', 'sample_list' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View sample list', 'sample_list' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search sample list', 'sample_list' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No customer feedback found', 'sample_list' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No customer feedback found in Trash', 'sample_list' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent sample list:', 'sample_list' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'sample list', 'sample_list' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'List of feedback from customer to display',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' =>false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'sample_list', $args );
}

add_action("admin_menu", "addMyMenus");

function addMyMenus() {

    add_submenu_page("themes.php", "My Submenu", "My Submenu", 'manage_options', "my-submenu-slug", "fd_sample_list");
}
```

As you can see I try to add the `fd_sample_test()` function into my `add_submenu_page` callback function. I add my `add_submenu_page() to appearance menu then the`add_submenu_page()`will call the`register_post_type()`. I don't know if this is possible but if you have tutorial, that will be great to study for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found the following blog post very helpful
https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-add-wordpress-cpt-admin-menu-as-sub-menu/

For a quick start, use the following. Read the full blog to get the highlighting/active page to work:

1. show_in_menu args MUST false

   ```
   register_post_type( 'your-cpt', array(
   'description'           => '',
   'public'                => true,
   'show_ui'               => true,
   'show_in_menu'          => false, /* Do not show admin menu */
   [...] 
   ) );
   ```
2. Add Submenu to parent

   ```
   add_submenu_page(
       'upload.php',                 // parent slug
       'Your CPT Title',             // page title
       'Sub Menu Title',             // sub-menu title
       'edit_posts',                 // capability
       'edit.php?post_type=your-cpt' // your menu menu slug
   );
   ```